# Play embeded youtube video JS

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, playback

I am embedding a youtube video using the iframe tag, but am unsuccessful at accessing the object's play functionality.  Here is how I am loading the object:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0">
```

I've referenced the APIs, but I don't really understand how to access the play/pause functionality.  I have tried using jquery as follows, but the captured object doesn't have the desired attributes:

```
vid = $('#player')
vid.playVideo() // doesn't work
```

I have also tried using the swfsobject as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/embed/ngf03kCRw3s",
                       "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);

  </script>
```

However, nothing appears on the page (and there are no errors in the console).  Help is appreciated, Thanks,

Comment: You need to use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). You can start with the [Youtube JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)

Comment: Do you see an error in my swfobject code?  Not sure why it wouldn't work, just copied the example.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to play an embedded YouTube video with jQuery (and JS) is by appending the parameter "autoplay=1" to the src attribute of the iframe.
In your case, the code would be something like this:

```
$("#player")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
```

Another example by [Martin Wolf](https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/dyLAC):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {
 
    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();
 
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="play-video" href="#">Play Video</a><br />
 
<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And that's it. The video will start to play.
If someone needs the solution in Vanilla JS please leave a comment and I'll come back to update the answer when I have some extra time.